# How to use OpenLayers with MapGuide source

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, mapguide

Basically I want the following example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mapguide.html to worj against this WMS datasource "http://gis.aarhus.dk/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?USERNAME=Anonymous&";

All I have done so far is changing the url.

```
   var url = "http://gis.aarhus.dk/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?USERNAME=Anonymous&";
```

I found the following online docs http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/MapGuide-js.html but I dont know where to get the correct values for these parameters.

```
    var metersPerUnit = 111319.4908;  //value returned from mapguide
    var inPerUnit = OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT.m * metersPerUnit;
    OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["dd"] = inPerUnit;
    OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["degrees"] = inPerUnit;
    OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 96;

        var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-87.764987, 43.691398, -87.695522, 43.797520);
        var tempScales = [100000, 51794.74679, 26826.95795, 13894.95494, 7196.85673, 3727.59372, 1930.69773, 1000];

        var params = {
            mapdefinition: 'Library://Samples/Sheboygan/MapsTiled/Sheboygan.MapDefinition',
            basemaplayergroupname: "Base Layer Group"
        };
```

How do I get the correct values for the above parameters?

Comment: Ok, I have figured some of the parameters - after talking to the host of the MapGuid server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get information about WMS from GetCapabilities request that in your case should look like this:

http://gis.aarhus.dk/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?USERNAME=Anonymous&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1

Comment: http://gis.aarhus.dk/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&FORMAT=text/xml worked. But only gave some of the information.