# OpenLayers 3 - Wrong ScaleLine value with Gauss-Boaga projection

Tags: scale, openlayers-3, projection

I'm using openlayers 3 to render a map from a mapserver server. I need to use Gauss Boaga projection, so I defined:

```
var gbProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:3003',
    extent: [1290650.93, 4192956.42, 2226749.10, 5261004.57],
    units: 'm'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(gbProjection);
var mymap = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend(
            [new ol.control.FullScreen(), new ol.control.ScaleLine({
                    units: 'metric'
                })]),
    layers: layers,
    units: 'm',
    target: 'mymap',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: gbProjection,
        center: [gbest, gbnord],
        zoom: 9
    })
});
```

I added the projection in the "view" field. Everything is working fine, I'm able to place my points on the map in the correct position. The only issue is I'm getting wrong values inside the ScaleLine, it seems the real scale multiplied by 100000 (I'm getting, say 50000 Km instead of 500 m). I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Not sure about this but would think it has something to do with projection.  According to http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html maybe you need to play with `metersPerUnit` property of projection???

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I added that option to the projection object, but I had same results. I used 100000 as "metersPerUnit"....

Comment: Here is an example using `metsPerUnit`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922099/how-to-use-openlayers-with-mapguide-source Not sure if this will help or not..

Answer (score 0):

include the proj4js library within your project:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js`

And then make ol3 aware about EPSG:3003 by adding this line:

`Proj4js.defs["EPSG:3003"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs";`

Then do following to set the extent and get a reference to your projection.

```
//get a reference of your new projection
var gbProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3003');
//set the extent
gbProjection.setExtent( [1290650.93, 4192956.42, 2226749.10, 5261004.57]);
```

The projection defininition may be found here
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/monte-mario-italy-zone-1/proj4js/

Using this way your scale should be fine and you will also be able to do any tranformations.

Comment: Thanks @pavlos, but I had to slightly modify your example like this: window.Proj4js = {
                    Proj: function (code) {
                        return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]);
                    },
                    defs: proj4.defs,
                    transform: proj4
                };
                Proj4js.defs("EPSG:3003", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs");
                var gbProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3003');